# Why can't i declare a more than three digits array of array of char in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program that takes an integer and then makes array of arrays of char and finds the number of every occurrence of every char in all lines. This two dimensional array has the size of "lineNumber". The code is shown below.
The problem is when i get an input more than 3 digits, it stops working and exits. I really found that the problem is with declaring the array of array of chars. Can you tell me how to overcome this problem? For example i want to take an input of 1000 line?
The problem is not with the scanf function, i know that. Can you fix my code?

```c
printf("Number of lines: ");
int lineNumber;
int n = scanf("%d", &lineNumber);
if (n == 0) {
   puts("Use integers.");
   return n;
}
char lines[lineNumber][1024]; /* It can't declare more than 3 digit integer */
int i = 0;
for (;i < lineNumber; i++) {
   printf("%d: ", i+1);
   fgets(lines[i], 1024, stdin);
   lines[i][strlen(lines[i])-1] = '\0';
}

/* count the number of occurrence of every char in all lines */
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. This code looks weird as it is.

Comment: This is not an array of pointers to char, but an array of arrays of chars

Comment: Stack space is limited, use dynamic allocation?

Comment: " The problem is not with the scanf function" --> Yes it is.  It leaves `\n` in `stdin`.

Comment: ` lines[i][strlen(lines[i])-1] = '\0';` will replace the last character of the line with a nul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If lineNumber is for example `9000`:

```
char lineptr[lineNumber][1024];
```

then `lineptr` uses about `9000*1024 = 9MB` of stack space. Depending on your os and system configuration, this might be too much crashing your program. Stack space is usually limited.

If you need a big amount of space, better allocate the memory with `malloc()`.

Comment: Because this isn't noting that the maximum value of a `char` is 128. Any 4-digit number would cause overflow.

Comment: @JL2210  the value is _not_ stored in a char, but used to declare the array size (VLA)

Comment: Or, you could use a static variable and maybe change the mcmodel.  You have the benefit of not having to care about freeing the memory.  Only if you know some reasonable size bounds at compile time, though.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes, that's another option. However, since the size of the array is read at runtime, I fear this is not feasible heer